# Account deleted without notice?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I logged in to my account today, posted an answer to a question and an edit to an answer. The next thing I know, my account was logged out, my user was deleted and my answer was removed.

- Account:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/589723/brianjm
- [Answer created today:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362349/iphone-test-automation-need-software)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlTVh.png
- [Answer edited today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939539/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-vbs-files-for-functions-in-qtp):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbGur.png

I don't understand why my account was deleted.

Comment: what methods did you use to login to the site? Perhaps you accidentally created a new account by signing in with different credentials? You can see your login details [in your profile](http://i.imgur.com/GWZjr.png)

Comment: There's a comment on your answer that reads: "This reads like brochure material." – Andrew Barber 49 mins ago, Your account probably appeared to be a spammer account.

Comment: So the policy is to simply delete an account when an answer appears to "read like brochure material"? It certainly is not brochure material.

Comment: No, not at all. We're just guessing with what might be minor indicators.

Comment: I'm not a moderator - let alone the one who deleted your account. But I can say that we are very harsh on spammers. I'm not saying that you are spamming, but your answer seemed to be an advertisement for a product.

Comment: So can I get my old account back? If I post the same answer again, is this account then going to be deleted?

Comment: I'd say on a quick glance, this read like brochure material but on a more thorough one, it didn't. Moderators have very little time to look at the posts they moderate. This action may well get reversed, I'll flag this post and ask a mod to take a look at the issue

Comment: And to save everyone else the searching, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13166648/922184 (10k link)

Comment: In any case, you don't look like a spammer to me. You just got unlucky enough to get caught in this. Just sit and wait for the mods to decide what to do.

Comment: Well, regarding your answer which was deleted, it was deleted by Brad Larson. You'll have to wait for him to reply. It seems strange to me that your account was deleted without notice, even if you possibly were a repeated offender. There's usually some sort of warning. Just wait for a diamond's answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha If it's a spammer, there's no warning. Not saying this user is a spammer, though, and also not saying that the account was deleted because a mod thought they were spamming (likely scenario, but not the only possibility).

Comment: I was the one who flagged and commented, though perhaps someone else flagged as well. The post in question read like advertising material to me; it seemed a bit out of the realm of a normal 'fan' posting about their favorite tool. I was surprised to see the account deleted, however. I'll guess Brad had a good reason, or it was a mis-click. There were no other answers on the account though, so I'm not sure if it's too important to get the account back, per se. (though that's not up to me, is it!)

Comment: @Pekka: There's nothing a moderator can do; the account was nuked from orbit.  It's a "do-over" at this point.

Comment: @Robert ah, okay. In that case, it would be interesting to know what caused the nuking - was it only that answer? Or is that information lost as well? Just so the OP knows what to expect.

Comment: @Pekka My account was around for years. This was my first answer and edit, ever.

Comment: @Pekka: The information is lost.  The account had only two activities, which the OP has helpfully screen-shotted here.  It doesn't really matter how old the account is; if the total activity is only spammy, we'll push the reset button.  We don't burn accounts if there is *any* evidence whatsoever of productive activity, as that would cause actual data loss.  In this particular case, the remedy is to simply create a new account.

Comment: @BrianJM: All I can really say about this is just make sure you have two or three upvoted (read: valuable to the community) non-promotional answers on your new account, and you'll be more or less permanently protected against nuking (we'll send you a mod message first, if overly promotional activity is occurring).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am OK with the new account. To be clear - it seems the consensus is that the post was "spammy" at first glace, but not when re-read. The (likely) reason the account was deleted was because of one spam flag combined with an otherwise inactive account. Now that I have posts on my account, in the future, my account should not be deleted for a potentially "spammy" comment, correct?

Comment: Your ["first" post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13167555/102937) looks good.  Note that @AutomatedChaos won't get notified (@-replies only work in comments, which you'll be able to post after you gain 50 reputation).  Happy hunting.

Comment: @BrianJM I don't agree that the post looks less spammy on closer inspection; I read it quite thoroughly before flagging, as I usually do. What made it trip my "spam" senses was how *hard it tried* to push one solution over another - using so much wording that one could find in a brochure or 'testimonial'. That might simply be your writing style. However, as Robert noted; with more 'normal' activity on the account, borderline things tend not to look as spammy. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was the one who deleted your account.

I did so after reading your answer, which was flagged as spam. For posterity, this is what it contained:

> Since you are looking for a solution that does not rely on
>   jailbreaking or rooting a device, Perfecto Mobile will not suffice.
>   What you are looking for is the M-eux [QTP Mobile Testing](http://northwaysolutions.com/solutions/automated-mobile-testing/)
>   solution.
>
> M-eux integrates directly with QTP (add-in), Visual Studio and
>   Eclipse. There is no need to jailbreak or root devices and it offers
>   true object recognition (so you can utilize your existing QTP skills).
>   The mobile device can be connect directly to your computer (USB),
>   accessed through a WiFi connection or accessed remotely in a lab
>   (on-site or off-site).
>
> M-eux has a track record of promptly supporting the newest devices and
>   latest OS versions. M-eux supported iOS 6 the day it was released.
>   Perfecto still doesn't support it (and can't until it is jailbroken);
>   you won't find an iPhone 5 in their list of supported devices.
>   Jailbreaking tablets in the USA violates the DMCA (effective Jan
>   2013), which obviously  presents challenges for solutions that rely on
>   jailbroken devices.

It reads like it's straight out of a brochure, and points to a commercial service while attacking another. I found it very hard to believe that a neutral third party would write a post like this.

We have had a significant volume of spam posted today from a series of new user accounts. If a new account looks entirely created to spam, with no indication that it's a real user or someone who's simply unaware of our promotional rules, we tend to destroy those accounts.

The fact that this was the first and only answer by a new user to a question that was months old, it read like an ad, and I'd just dealt with four or five other spammers dumping answers across the site, caused me to lean toward the destruction of this account. Deletion of an account is extremely difficult to undo, so I only use it where I am certain the account isn't legitimate and there is nothing else of value attached to it.

Hopefully you can see the indications that led me to this. Nothing of significance was lost by removing this account, aside from your time in creating a new one. You've already done this, and started posting good looking answers with that, so there's not a lot more we can do here. I apologize for the inconvenience, but we tend to be pretty harsh on spam here.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You may close this question.